# InfoWindow for iOS Google Maps that resizes depending on the size of subviews

Tags: ios, google-maps, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to make an autolayout InfoWindow. Fixed views seem easy enough with a XIB e.g.
[image: an infowindow]

I'd like to automatically resize the view so the width and height are relative to the label size and potentially any other subviews that are added e.g. images.

[I have tried this approach from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051617/how-to-resize-a-parent-view-based-on-the-size-of-subviews-layouted-with-autolayo) without success, but will blame that on Fridayitis perhaps..