# How to resize UIContainerView according to fit embedded UILabel Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a `UIContainerView` that its embedded `UIViewController` contains a `UILAbel` and two `UIButton`. The `UILabel` text has a dynamic number of lines and it expands according to the number of it's number of lines. What I'm asking for is how to make the `UIContainerView` expands to fit the new embedded label size?

I am using `autolayout constraints` to manage the label height.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIContainerView *view;
.....
label.text = @"Some text";
[label sizeToFit];

CGRect viewFrame = view.frame;
viewFrame.size = label.frame.size;
view.frame = viewFrame;
```

Comment: I'm using `autolayout constraints`. Is there any way to handle  it the same way without setting the frame size?

Comment: You need set correct auto layout settings of parent view. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051617/how-to-resize-a-parent-view-based-on-the-size-of-subviews-layouted-with-autolayo